# change bar color dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Problem Statement:

I want to create a bar which will change color based on the number i provide. The bar will go up and down with transition.
For Eg: if number is 80: on hover bar will start from red and around 50 it will become light red and as it reaches 80 will be pretty much green.

As per my code i am able to acheive this by modifying the % of white. Any way by which i can send the number to css so that the linear-gradient property picks it up.

Here is my code:

```css
.container{
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 600px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white 50%,green 50%,red);
    transition: background-position 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to pass a variable value directly into your css class.
You define your custom variable in css by `var(--NameOfYourVar)`. And in your html part you can use the style property to pass a value to your variable.

```css
.container{
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 600px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white var(--myVar),green 50%,red);
    transition: background-position 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--myVar: 80%;">
</div>
```

But I'm not sure if this already fully supported by all browsers.

Comment: CSS variables are not supported in IE, but [seems to be supported in all decent browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables). Oh, and you’re even able to modify the value on-the-go using Javascript. E.g. `document.querySelector(".container").style.setProperty("--myVar","80%")`